# Issue - different WEEK number showing from php WEEK function and mysql WEEK function?

Tags: php, mysql

I Want to get the current **Week** and **Previous Week**.
I used to get the current week using php like below.

```
$week = date("W");
```

This will return the week number as **50**.

If i use mysql like below

```
select WEEK('2019-12-13') as this_week
```

I am getting the current week as **49**

If i pass the `$week` in my sql database i am not getting any value for this week transaction.

Why this is happening and how can i get the current week and previous week accurately?

Comment: This is happening because your PHP code and MySQL have different timezone configured.

Comment: You want to get current and previous week using PHP or MySQL?

Comment: There are different rules for establishing week numbers, so check the default rules as they pertain to each of the relevant functions.

Comment: @vinay Patil, from php want to get the week and pss it to my php function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
WEEK(date[,mode])
```

> This function returns the week number for date. The two-argument form of WEEK() enables you to specify whether the week starts on Sunday or Monday and **whether the return value should be in the range from 0 to 53 or from 1 to 53**.

[MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week)

So your weeks on MySQL are zero-based because the `default_week_format` is `0`.
Use `3` as parameter to get your desired result:

```
select week(curdate(), 3) as this_week
```

To get the last week you could do

```
select week(curdate() - interval 7 day, 3) as last_week
```

Comment: thank you,how can i get the previous  week number from current date

Comment: The php doc says "ISO-8601 week number of year, weeks starting on Monday Example: 42 (the 42nd week in the year)" which sounds to me like MySQL mode 3, not 1.  Unless they are just being imprecise and actually meant "Example: 42 (the 43rd week in the year)".  I don't have php to try it out.

Answer (score 2):

There are different rules for establishing week numbers, so check the default rules as they pertain to each of the relevant functions. MySQL's WEEK() function allows you to choose from a variety of 'modes' - rules which establish where weeks are counted from

```
select WEEK('2019-12-13');
+--------------------+
| WEEK('2019-12-13') |
+--------------------+
|                 49 |
+--------------------+

select WEEK('2019-12-13',1);
+----------------------+
| WEEK('2019-12-13',1) |
+----------------------+
|                   50 |
+----------------------+
```

Comment: thank you,how can i get the previous  week number from current date

Comment: If you have a different question, please ask a different question, but in general the previous week is 7 days before the current date.

Comment: Sorry, I asked both in same question :)

Comment: So, now you know how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL and PHP by default use **different algorithms** to determine the week number.

Supposing you want to **replicate in PHP MySQL's algorithm**, i.e. get the same number that MySQL would return, then

```
/** MySQL's WEEK() function ISO8601-2 (European) */
function isodate($date) {
    list($y, $m, $d) = explode('-', $date);
    $timestamp  = mktime(12, 12, 12, $m, $d, $y);
    $doy        = date('z', $timestamp);
    $dow        = date('w', $timestamp);
    return floor((7+$doy-$dow)/7);
}
```

Always be sure to verify your algorithm:

```
$db     = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=test;', 'user', 'pass');
$stmt   = $db->prepare("SELECT WEEK(?) AS x");
$diff   = 0;
$checks = 0;

print " Anno    |   01   |   02   |   03   |   04   |   05   |   06   |   07   |\n";
// Controllo solo Gennaio e Dicembre, approfittando wilmente del fatto che hanno entrambi 31 giorni
foreach ([ 1, 12 ] as $month) {
    for ($year = 1999; $year <= 2022; $year++) {
        for ($day = 1; $day <= 31; $day++) {
            // Build a timestamp from the date
            $date = mktime(12, 12, 12, $month, $day, $year);
            $intl = date('Y-m-d', $date);
            if ($day === 1) {
                print date('M Y ', $date);
            }
            // Ask the date to MySQL
            $stmt->execute([ $intl ]);
            $data  = $stmt->fetch();
            $mysql = (int)$data['x'];
            // $php   = date('W', $date);
            $php   = (int)isodate($intl);
            $checks ++;
            if ($mysql !== $php) {
                $diff++;
            }
            printf('|%s %02d/%d', date('D', $date), $php, $mysql);
        }
        print("|\n");
    }
}
print("{$checks} checks, {$diff} differences\n");
```

$ php -q test.php | grep "differences"

1488 checks, 0 differences